# How to select text in HTML tag without a tag around it (JSoup)

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup

I would like to select the text inside the strong-tag but without the div under it...

Is there a possibility to do this with jsoup directly?

My try for the selection (doesn't work, selects the full content inside the strong-tag):

```
Elements selection = htmlDocument.select("strong").select("*:not(.dontwantthatclass)");
```

HTML:

```
<strong>
   I want that text
   <div class="dontwantthatclass">
   </div>
</strong>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking for the [ownText()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) method.

```
String txt = htmlDocument.select("strong").first().ownText();
```

Comment: Your answer was better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at various methods jsoup have to deal with it https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html. You can use `remove()`, `removeChild()` etc.
One thing you can do is use regex.
Here is a sample regex that matches start and end tag also appended by `</br>` tag
https://www.debuggex.com/r/1gmcSdz9s3MSimVQ

So you can do it like

```
selection.replace(/<([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\/\1>|<[^\/]+\/>/ig, "");
```

You can further modify this regex to match most of your cases.

Another thing you can do is, further process your variable using javascript or vbscript:-

```
Elements selection = htmlDocument.select("strong")
```

jquery code here:-

```
var removeHTML = function(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector).remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}
```

With regular expression you can use ownText() methods of jsoup to get and remove unwanted string.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using jQuery, so you could use "innerText" property on your "strong" element:

```
var selection = htmlDocument.select("strong")[0].innerText;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scratch_cf/8ds4uwLL/

PS: If you want to wrap the retrieved text into a "strong" tag, I think you'll have to build a new element like `$('<strong>retrievedText</strong>');`